# Cauchy sequence in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis

I am currently lost on proving the below.

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and $d$ a metric on $X$. Let ${x_n}$ be a Cauchy sequence in 
$(X; d)$. Show that there exists a $k\in N$ such that $x_n = x_k$ for all $n\geq k$.

I attempted to use the fact that all Cauchy sequences are bounded but I got lost even further. Your help will highly be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you have stated something incorrectly.

Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric $d(x,y) = |x - y|$. Then define the convergent (hence Cauchy) sequence $\{x_n\}$ by

$$x_n = \frac{1}{n}.$$

Then clearly, for all $k \in N$, $\frac{1}{k} \neq \frac{1}{n}$ for $n > k$.